# What does the random_state parameter do in sklearn's ParameterSampler?

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, sampling

I am trying to implement sklearn's [ParameterSampler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterSampler.html), but I'm not completely sure what the `random_state` parameter does.

My guess is that if `random_state` is set to `None`, then normal random sampling is used. And if `random_state` is something other than `None`, then pseudo random sampling is used?

Also I'm not sure how different int values affect the sampling. For example, is `random_state = 1` different form `random_state = 2`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/utilities.html):

> If `random_state` is `None` or `np.random`, then a randomly-initialized `RandomState` object is returned.
>
> If `random_state` is an integer, then it is used to seed a new `RandomState` object.
>
> If `random_state` is a `RandomState` object, then it is passed through.

Basically, by setting the `random_state`, you guarantee that the (pseudo-) random number generator generates the same sequence of random integers each time, which in turn has an effect on the way your data is sampled.

Answer (score 4):

`random_state` does not affects the distribution. It is a parameter that enables you to get consistent results. If you set it to 1, every time you run the code you'll get the same result. If you set it to 2, this will happen as well (but probably with different values than before). If you set it to None (the default), each time random seed is chosen, and you'll get different results.

Answer (score 0):

This **random_state** parameter in sklearn provides a seed value to the function's internal random number generator.
During If we choose different values for that seed value, that will result in different randomized splits for training and test. So, if we want to get the same training and test split each time, we need to make sure to pass in the same value of the random state parameter. So it is something like random.seed() code.